Can a generic function take a custom type as an argument in Rust?
So I did manage to make a generic function where I can use the default types:
fn arithmetic_operation<T, F>(a: T, b: T, operation: F) -> T
where 
    T: Copy,
    F: Fn(T, T) -> T,
{
    operation(a, b)
}

fn main() {
    // f64
    let result_f64 = arithmetic_operation(2.0, 3.0 , |x, y| x+y);
    println!("Result  f64: {:?}", result_f64);
    // Result  f64: 5.0

    // i128
    let result_i128 = arithmetic_operation(2i128, 3i128 , |x, y| x+y);
    println!("Result  i128: {:?}", result_i128);
    // Result  i128: 5
}

playground
I would like to create some custom types (like money,  km, ...) and still use generic functions. But I can't figure out how to write a function signature for custom types.
If I write a custom type defined with an enum:
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum ResType {
    Int(i128),
    Float(f64),
}

impl ResType {
    fn get_i128(self) -> i128 {
        match self {
            ResType::Int(val)  => val,
            ResType::Float(val) => val as i128
        }
    }

    fn get_f64(self) -> f64 {
        match self {
            ResType::Int(val)  => val as f64,
            ResType::Float(val) => val
        }
    }

    fn is_float(&self) -> bool {
        matches!(self, ResType::Float(_) )
    }
}

fn arithmetic_operation<T, F>(a: ResType, b: ResType, func: F) -> ResType 
where 
    T: Copy,
    F: Fn(T, T) -> T,
{
    if a.is_float() || b.is_float() {
        let res = func(a.get_f64(), b.get_f64());
        return ResType::Float(res);
    }

    let res = func(a.get_i128(), b.get_i128());
    ResType::Int(res)
}


fn main() {
    let a = ResType::Int(42);
    let b = ResType::Int(13);

    println!("Result ResType: {:?}", arithmetic_operation(a, b, |x,y| x+y));
}

playground
I have some errors explaining that a T is required, but an f64 is given.
note: expected type parameter `T`, found `f64`
  --> src/main.rs:33:24
   |
33 |         let res = func(a.get_f64(), b.get_f64());
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `f64`

How can I make this type of generic function work with a custom type ?
Or is this a wrong approach altogether to create new types ?

The problem here is that the code which calls arithmetic_operation gets to decide what F is and in particular what type its arguments are.  In any given call, there can only be one such concrete type.  Suppose a caller provides a func that accepts f64 but the ResType instances are actually Ints.  It's not clear what you intend to happen in such cases instead?

You would want that operation have a polymorphic type, e.g. F : for <T : MyAddableTrait> Fn(T, T) -> T, however this type is not supported by Rust (see for example here to find a workaround).

You cannot add two factors of type ResType.
Instead, you have to consider how to link the variants of ResType.
Better is to implement the trait From for f64 and i128 instead of the homebrewed functions get_f64() and get_i128().There are traits for the most arithmetic functions in Rust, e.g. Add that you could implement for your ResType. 
Here is a working version of your program:
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum ResType {
    Int(i128),
    Float(f64),
}

impl From<ResType> for i128 {
    fn from(rt: ResType) -> i128 {
        match rt {
            ResType::Int(val) => val,
            ResType::Float(val) => val as i128, // loss of accuracy!
        }
    }
}

impl From<ResType> for f64 {
    fn from(rt: ResType) -> f64 {
        match rt {
            ResType::Int(val) => val as f64,
            ResType::Float(val) => val,
        }
    }
}

fn arithmetic_operation(a: ResType, b: ResType, func: fn(ResType, ResType) -> ResType) -> ResType {
    (func)(a, b)
}

fn main() {
    let a = ResType::Int(42);
    let b = ResType::Int(13);

    println!(
        "Result ResType: {:?}",
        arithmetic_operation(a, b, |a: ResType, b: ResType| {
            match a {
                ResType::Int(i) => {
                    // loss of accuracy if b is Float!
                    ResType::Int(i + i128::from(b))
                }
                ResType::Float(f) => ResType::Float(f + f64::from(b)),
            }
        })
    );
}

Playground

It's not exactly the question I asked, but the  best I could end up with.
I created a new type with Struct to represent a custom type.
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Money {
    amount: f64
}

// Constructor
impl Money {
    pub fn new(amount: f64) -> Self{
        Money {
            amount: amount
        }
    }
}

impl Display for Money {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} €", self.amount)
    }
}

To support a generic add operation for my custom type.
I first created a way to transform it into an f64.
impl Into<f64> for Money {
    fn into(self: Money) -> f64 {
        self.amount
    }
}

Then we can implement a generic add operation that can take any type that can be converted into an f64.
impl<T> Add<T> for Money
where
    T: Into<f64>,
{
    type Output = Money;

    fn add(self: Money, other: T) -> Money {
        let result = self.amount + other.into();
        Money { amount: result}
    }

}

We can now add our type to every type that can be converted into an f64. But not larger int types like i64 or i128.
fn arithmetic_operation<T, U, F>(a: T, b: U, operation: F) -> T
where 
    F: Fn(T, U) -> T,
{
    operation(a, b)
}

fn main() {
    // We support adding either f64
    let money = Money::new(42.0);
    let res = money + 1337.0; // add f64
    println!("{}", res);

    //  or i32
    let i: i32 = 22;
    let res = money + i; // add i32
    println!("{}", res);

    // With our generic function
    let a = Money::new(42.0);
    let b = 1337.0;
    let res = arithmetic_operation(a, b, |x, y| x+y);
    println!("Generic function: {}", res);
}

playground
It's not possible at the moment to add a specific implementation in Rust when there is a generic implementation.
But it's possible to create multiple specific implementations:
impl Add<Money> for Money
{
    type Output = Money;

    fn add(self: Money, other: Money) -> Money {
        let result = self.amount + other.amount;
        Money { amount: result}
    }
}

impl Add<f64> for Money
{
    type Output = Money;

    fn add(self: Money, other: f64) -> Money {
        let result = self.amount + other;
        Money { amount: result}
    }
}

impl Add<i64> for Money
{
    type Output = Money;

    fn add(self: Money, other: i64) -> Money {
        let other: f64 = other as f64; // loss of precision here
        Money { amount: self.amount + other}
    }
}


Wherever possible, you should implement the From instead of the Into trait. The documentation states that if you have implemented the From trait on your type, Into will call it when needed. Note, however, that the opposite is not true: if you implement Into on your type, it will not automatically come with an implementation of From.
